# Why is this function clearing screen output?

Tags: functions

This is an example script which is meant to print the keyboard shortcut for a command.

Applying it clears the screen output. The result of commands like `intro` or `version` get cleared off the screen when it is enabled. Currently it only calls `echomsg` when the last command is `tabnew` yet the screen gets cleared when any other command is applied.

Why is this happening?

```
cnoremap <silent> <cr> <cr>:call <SID>CommandCallback()<cr>

function! s:CommandCallback()
  let last_command = @:

  if last_command =~ 'tabnew'
    echomsg "Tabnew was called"
  endif
endfunction
```

PS: The question where this script came from -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691961

Comment: Because of everything else in the mapping. Suggestion: you might find 'titlestring' more convenient as a place to display information.

Comment: @Antony By `titlestring`  do you mean `titlestring "Tabnew was called"`?

Comment: I mean the `'titlestring'` option.